# Vadidar campos que no se repitan al importar excel

Tags: laravel, excel, laravel-blade, laravel-excel

Hola gente necestio importar un excel con unas cuentas las cuales deben ser unicas, el import como tal ya esta y la validacion la hice con un try catch pero necesito saber cual es el numero que se esta repitiendo porque hasta el momento solo me arroja la alerta que captura el catch pero sin el numero que necesito

```
class PucImport implements ToModel
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Puc([
            'codigoCuenta'=> $row[0],
            'codigoSuperior'=> $row[1],
            'nombreCuenta'=> $row[2],
            'fuentefinanciacionSIA_id'=> 12,
            'codigoEntidadFinancieraSIA_id'=> 29,
            'cuentaMaestra_id'=> 8,
            'futExcedentesLiquidez_id'=> 1,
            'empresa_id'=> 1,
            'conceptoDian_id'=> 102,
            'formatoDian_id'=> 8,
            'opcionesPrivilegios_id'=> 8,
            'tipoCuenta_id'=> $row[3],
            'naturalezaCuenta'=> $row[4],
            'nivel'=> $row[5],
        ]);
    }
}
```

`

```
    public function import(Request $request)
    {
       try {
            $request->hasFile('excel');
            $archivo = $request->file('excel');
            Excel::import(new PucImport, $archivo);
            return  redirect()->route('puc.index')->with('message', 'Cuentas PUC Creadas Correctamente');
       }
       catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
           //dd($archivo);
           Session::flash('message','Un número de cuenta ya fue registrado y no puede estar duplicado por favor verifica tu excel.');
           return redirect()->route('puc.index');
       }
    }
`
```

Comment: ¿Todos los campos de esa tabla deben de ser únicos?, de ser así, lo que buscarías más bien es añadir índices únicos en tus tablas de la base de datos y validar eso mediante un `Request` o un `Validator`.

Comment: No solo uno el campo Numero de cuenta